# What to do when I cant compile my project after making it x64 compatible in msvc2010?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, 64-bit

What to do when I cant compile my project after making it x64 compatible in msvc2010?

I recently had a hard time adding a x64 platform to msvc2010 and now when I want to compile, I get these error messages:

```
1>src\CarClass.cpp(130): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
1>src\CarClass.cpp(130): warning C4267: 'return' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
```

P.S. I will look deeper into the code and try to google the best out of what I have right now.

Comment: step 1: understand what the error means. (But you do that every time you get an error... right?)

Comment: whatever suits you. Instead of saying something like "Hey you should use static_cast<int>(data)"...

Comment: Do you want to fix the error or ignore it?

Comment: Or to understand why it is an error in x64?

Comment: would like to know why it's an error in x64 exactly!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your warnings are treated as errors. If you want to change this, do this:

```
Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> General
```

and make sure that `Treat Warnings as Errors` is set to `No`.

If you want to go further and address the warning, you should post the line of code that produces the warning and then further help can be given.

Comment: Usually, the IDE is *not* set to treat warnings as errors by default.  Merely changing to a 64-bit build does not do this.  That's the strange thing.  So my answer assumes that this is not what the OP wanted.  Yes, the OP can look further into the warning.

Comment: Well, when I compile my project the way suggested, then I get some strange stuff going on, so I assume the errors\warnings are there for a reason.

Comment: @JohnYouDontLike - You need to explain what the "strange stuff going on" is.  What my answer explains is to turn off the "Treat warnings as errors" option, which is what your post describes.  Once you do that, then the *error* goes away, but you still get to see what the warning is.

Comment: @JohnYouDontLike - The error/warning is there because you are assigning size_t (64 bits long) to an int (32 bits long), which might not fit:  [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b2e7499.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b2e7499.aspx).